# Jekyll content being duplicated on page

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm using github pages with the `bulma-clean-theme`, and when I render my page locally, it shows up fine and with no issue.  However when I view blog posts on my site on github, I see the content duplicated on the site!

[image: depicts a webpage with the site content repeated two times]

Here is the most likely area for this to result, in my changes to `pages.html` from the theme.

```
<div class="content">

    <h2><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></h2>
      <div class="meta"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Published {{ page.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }} by 
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> FoxDeploy
        <i class="fa fa-hourglass" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i>{{ content | reading_time_as_s }} average reading time</i>
      </div>      
      <a href="{{ post.url }}"><img src="{{ post.header }}{{ post.coverImage }}"></a><br>   
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error!

I was using the `"jekyll-time-to-read"` gem, which is not supported on github pages.  This plugin would handle calculating the time it takes to read a post by parsing the `content`  through a new liquid command.

```
 <i>{{ content | reading_time_as_s }} average reading time</i>
```

Since it wasn't supported though, instead the page would be rendered with the entire content of the post, then a lame trailing `average reading time` after the post.

The fix, for now, was to remove that bit from my post and also remove the plugin, and the problem was solved.